# Expand div with both variable height and width

Tags: css, html, height

I'm trying to create a div that will expand to the bottom of its container. The layout consists of two columns within a parent container. The width of both columns is a percentage, and the height of the parent container and the left column expands based on a slideshow in the left column. I'd like the height of the right column to match the left, so I can position something at the bottom. I've tried many different things, but to no avail. Here is the page:

http://whub30.webhostinghub.com/~scottl9/testindex2.html

The html is

```
<div id="content_section">
    <div class="imgwrap">
      <div class="imgwrap2">
         Left-column content
      </div>
      <div class="playersection">
         Right-column content
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="clearall"></div>
</div>
```

and the corresponding CSS is

```
 #content_section { position:relative; min-height:400px; min-width:600px; max-height: 1000px; max-width:2000px;}
.imgwrap {position:relative; width:100%; height:auto; min-width:409px; min-height:230px; border-style:solid; border-width:medium; display: inline-block;}
.imgwrap2 {position:relative; float:left; width:70%; height:auto;}
.playersection {border-style:solid; width:30%; position: relative; float: right; border-width:medium;}
.clearall {clear:both;}`
```

(I added borders so I could see the divs.)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of Right Column to 100%.

```
.imgwrap2 {position:relative; float:left; width:70%; height:100%;}
```

Comment: That's the left column, and I've tried that and it doesn't work. To set the height to a percentage, I would have had to set all of the containing heights to a percentage or to a set value. I can't do that since I want the height of both columns to expand with the image height in the left column.